# Oscillating Analog Readings

Tags: arduino-mega, sensors, analogread, op-amp

I am using a JIC 139 UV Sensor ([datasheet](http://www.eoc-inc.com/ifw/JIC%20137-138-139.pdf)) with an Arduino Mega 2560 and should be reading smooth curves as I bring a UV source to towards the sensor. Instead, my curves are increasing and oscillating. How can I remove the oscillations and what is the cause of these oscillations?

Code:

```
float mapfloat(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max)
{
    return (float)(x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (float)(in_max - in_min) + out_min;
}

int averageAnalogRead(int pinToRead)
{
    byte numberOfReadings = 8;
    unsigned int runningValue = 0;

    for(int x = 0 ; x < numberOfReadings ; x++)
        runningValue += analogRead(pinToRead);
    runningValue /= numberOfReadings;

    delay(100);

    return(runningValue);  
}

void setup() {
   Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

   float pinRead0 = averageAnalogRead(0);
   float pVolt0 = pinRead0 / 1024.0 * 5.0;

   // In mW/m^2
   Serial.println(pVolt0);
   //  Serial.println(mapfloat(pVolt0, 0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 15.0));

   delay(100);
}
```

`

Here is a sample screenshot from the Serial Plotter at 3 different distances from the UV Source: 
[image]

Would post cicuit but don't have enough reputation. Will post as response.
**edit:** I added a very large capacitor(3300 uf) between the output pin and ground which seemed to smooth the values a little bit but the noise still exists

**edit:** The x-axis is number of readings and the y-axis is voltage(0-5v) calculated from analogRead()

Comment: It is not your sketch, the sketch is okay. How stable is the 5V of the Arduino Uno ? It is most likely the analog circuit.

Comment: 5 volt is stable at 5.01, any ideas as to what may be wrong with the analog circuit?

Comment: What is the x-axis scale?  (Eg, is it reading number, time, etc)?  [Please edit  reply into your question]

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing circuit and construction details and oscilloscope traces, it's difficult or impossible to say what the problem is.  It may be due to op amp instability due to a large capacitive load.  It may reflect a beat frequency between some sensor and MCU signals, or aliasing between 60-Hz noise and your data-conversion rate.

Regarding op amp instability, see for example the article [*Op Amps Driving Capacitive Loads*, by Grayson King](http://www.analog.com/en/analog-dialogue/articles/ask-the-applications-engineer-25.html).  Here is a quote from that article:

> Q. *How does capacitive loading affect op amp performance?*
>   A. To put it simply, it can turn your amplifier into an oscillator. Here's how: [...]

Rather than just connecting that big 3300 μF capacitor to the output pin, perhaps instead try attaching an [Active Low Pass Filter](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_5.html) to the output, or a unity-gain op amp followed by a [Passive Low Pass Filter](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/filter/filter_2.html); etc.  Put big capacitors across power into the UV source and power into the sensor, instead of on the sensor output.

Regarding beat frequencies and aliasing, low-frequency oscillation like that seen in the trace may occur as a difference of two higher-frequency signals, or as a sampling artifact.  To check this out, attach an oscilloscope to the UV source and see if its power consumption oscillates; and/or try a more-rational sampling scheme than that shown in your code.

For example, instead of taking 8 readings within one millisecond in `averageAnalogRead()` and then waiting 100 ms, perhaps add a `delay(1)` inside the loop so that readings are spread out slightly more.  Remove the `delay(100)` from within `averageAnalogRead()`.  Compensate by changing the other `delay(100)` in `loop()` to, for example, `delay(191)` or `delay(193)`.  Try various delay amounts to see if they have an effect on the waveform.